# VSTS Release Management: Visual Studio Test Task

Tags: selenium, testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

We have a release definition setup within VSTS with a Visual Studio Test task to run our automated test suite. The problem we're experiencing is that the release is succeeding regardless of whether there are failing tests or not. There doesn't appear to be any control within the task configuration over the behaviour of error handling/test failures.

Does anybody have any workarounds or solutions for what we're trying to achieve?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Release Logs:

```
2018-04-10T07:50:31.6993593Z ##[section]Starting: Execute Automated Tests
2018-04-10T07:50:31.6999650Z ==============================================================================
2018-04-10T07:50:31.6999764Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2018-04-10T07:50:31.6999919Z Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah, etc. can also be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
2018-04-10T07:50:31.7000100Z Version      : 2.3.28
2018-04-10T07:50:31.7000183Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-04-10T07:50:31.7000292Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=835764)
2018-04-10T07:50:31.7000391Z ==============================================================================
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4137415Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4137720Z ========================================================
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4137953Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4138095Z Test assemblies : **\V6TestAutomation.dll
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4138483Z Test filter criteria : null
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4138620Z Search folder : D:\a\r1\a
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4138759Z Run settings file : D:\a\r1\a
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4138932Z Run in parallel : false
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4139050Z Run in isolation : false
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4139740Z Path to custom adapters : D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\packages
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4139868Z Other console options : null
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4140002Z Code coverage enabled : false
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4140402Z Rerun failed tests: true
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4140572Z Rerun failed tests threshold: 30
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4140686Z Rerun maximum attempts: 3
2018-04-10T07:50:32.4140862Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2018-04-10T07:50:33.9447744Z ========================================================
2018-04-10T07:50:34.1691886Z SystemVssConnection exists true
2018-04-10T07:50:34.1694146Z [command]D:\a\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.3.28\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe
2018-04-10T07:50:36.9541002Z ##########################################################################
2018-04-10T07:50:37.1168390Z Starting TestExecution Model...
2018-04-10T07:50:46.8510175Z **************** Starting test execution *********************
2018-04-10T07:50:46.8510636Z [command]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe @C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\d9500801-3c93-11e8-bd28-bd9645a0d16e.txt
2018-04-10T07:50:51.7078146Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.6.0
2018-04-10T07:50:51.7078766Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2018-04-10T07:50:51.8463454Z vstest.console.exe 
2018-04-10T07:50:51.8463809Z "D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll"
2018-04-10T07:50:51.8464039Z /logger:"trx"
2018-04-10T07:50:51.8464255Z /TestAdapterPath:"D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\packages"
2018-04-10T07:50:55.2887935Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2018-04-10T07:50:58.9435629Z SpecFlow+Runner execution started
2018-04-10T07:50:59.9152811Z SpecRun: running tests in D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll
2018-04-10T07:50:59.9153503Z Profile: Results
2018-04-10T07:51:00.3834652Z Discovering target: Default
2018-04-10T07:51:00.3834868Z Discovering tests from assembly: D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll
2018-04-10T07:51:04.1966900Z Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e) on port 1675
2018-04-10T07:51:04.1967270Z Only local connections are allowed.
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5791284Z Scenario: Create Record in TestTableExplorer -> Failed on thread #0
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5863835Z ##[error]  [ERROR] no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"serialNumber"}
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5915120Z ##[error]  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5917595Z ##[error]  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5919630Z Failed   Create Record
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5919860Z Error Message:
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5920023Z  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"serialNumber"}
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5920218Z   (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5920384Z   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5920571Z Stack Trace:
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5920736Z OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"serialNumber"}
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5920924Z   (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5921110Z   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5921294Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5921463Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5921666Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5921829Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5922006Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5922164Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5922735Z    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5923027Z    at V6TestAutomation.Areas.TestTableExplorer.TestTableExplorerSteps.WhenICreateARecord() in D:\a\1\s\V6TestAutomation\Areas\TestTableExplorer\TestTableExplorerSteps.cs:line 52
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5923250Z    at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5923463Z    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5924073Z    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5924298Z    at TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Runtime.RunnerTestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5924540Z    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5924743Z    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5924929Z    at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5925145Z    at V6TestAutomation.Areas.TestTableExplorer.TestTableExplorerFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5925381Z    at V6TestAutomation.Areas.TestTableExplorer.TestTableExplorerFeature.CreateRecord() in D:\a\1\s\V6TestAutomation\Areas\TestTableExplorer\TestTableExplorer.feature:line 10
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5925639Z    at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5926381Z    at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
2018-04-10T07:51:13.5926594Z    at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestAssemblyExecutor.ExecuteTestNodeTask(TestNode testNode, ITaskExecutor task, TraceEventType eventType)

** OMITTED FOR SIMPLICITY **

2018-04-10T07:51:16.0337874Z Standard Output Messages:
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0338025Z  Given the test table explorer page is displayed
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0338210Z  -> done: TestTableExplorerSteps.GivenTheTestTableExplorerPageIsDisplayed() (0.7s)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0338368Z  
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0338510Z  And a record exists in the records table
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0338697Z  -> error: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"serialNumber"}
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0338864Z ->   (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0339035Z ->   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0339209Z  
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0339345Z  When I delete a record
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0339491Z  -> skipped because of previous errors
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0339647Z  
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0339793Z  Then the record is not displayed in the records table
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0339955Z  -> skipped because of previous errors
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0340118Z Standard Error Messages:
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0340454Z  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"serialNumber"}
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0340705Z   (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0340935Z   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"serialNumber"}
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0341397Z   (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0341607Z   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0342023Z     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0342779Z     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0343045Z     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0343244Z     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0343450Z     at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<Id>b__0(ISearchContext context)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0343659Z     at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0343844Z     at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0344068Z     at V6TestAutomation.Areas.TestTableExplorer.TestTableExplorerSteps.WhenICreateARecord() in D:\a\1\s\V6TestAutomation\Areas\TestTableExplorer\TestTableExplorerSteps.cs:line 52
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0344295Z     at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0344530Z     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0344900Z     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0345120Z     at TechTalk.SpecRun.SpecFlowPlugin.Runtime.RunnerTestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0345350Z     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0345574Z     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0345762Z     at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0345972Z     at V6TestAutomation.Areas.TestTableExplorer.TestTableExplorerFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0346352Z     at V6TestAutomation.Areas.TestTableExplorer.TestTableExplorerFeature.DeleteRecord() in D:\a\1\s\V6TestAutomation\Areas\TestTableExplorer\TestTableExplorer.feature:line 17
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0346583Z     at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.ExecuteInternal(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0347340Z     at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TaskExecutors.StaticOrInstanceMethodExecutor.Execute(ITestThreadExecutionContext testThreadExecutionContext)
2018-04-10T07:51:16.0347580Z     at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestAssemblyExecutor.ExecuteTestNodeTask(TestNode testNode, ITaskExecutor task, TraceEventType eventType)
2018-04-10T07:51:25.4504774Z Result: 2 failed
2018-04-10T07:51:25.4505328Z   Total: 39
2018-04-10T07:51:25.4506188Z   Succeeded: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:25.4510416Z   Ignored: 37
2018-04-10T07:51:25.4511014Z   Pending: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:25.4511308Z   Skipped: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:25.4511584Z   Failed: 2
2018-04-10T07:51:25.4511843Z   Execution Time: 00:00:14.4039087
2018-04-10T07:51:25.4512174Z Report file: file:///D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075100.html
2018-04-10T07:51:25.4513035Z Log file: file:///D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075100.log
2018-04-10T07:51:25.4513325Z SpecFlow+Runner execution finished
2018-04-10T07:51:26.7860424Z Attachments:
2018-04-10T07:51:26.7861290Z   C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\gxkaqztp.ujc\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075100.log
2018-04-10T07:51:26.7861672Z   C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\gxkaqztp.ujc\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075100.html
2018-04-10T07:51:26.7862366Z Total tests: 39. Passed: 0. Failed: 2. Skipped: 37.
2018-04-10T07:51:26.7863031Z ##[error]Test Run Failed.
2018-04-10T07:51:26.7865279Z Test execution time: 28.6017 Seconds
2018-04-10T07:51:27.7157854Z Results File: D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\VssAdministrator_factoryvm-az261_2018-04-10_07_51_13.trx
2018-04-10T07:51:27.7162409Z **************** Completed test execution *********************
2018-04-10T07:51:27.7163247Z Test results files: D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\VssAdministrator_factoryvm-az261_2018-04-10_07_51_13.trx
2018-04-10T07:51:27.7789456Z Created test run: 450
2018-04-10T07:51:27.7790908Z Publishing test results: 39
2018-04-10T07:51:27.7846686Z Publishing test results to test run '450'.
2018-04-10T07:51:27.7875023Z Test results remaining: 39. Test run id: 450.
2018-04-10T07:51:28.8790810Z Published test results: 39
2018-04-10T07:51:28.8791160Z Publishing Attachments: 3
2018-04-10T07:51:29.8023722Z Failed tests: 2; Total tests: 39;
2018-04-10T07:51:29.9086633Z **************** Rerunning failed tests for Test run 450 *********************
2018-04-10T07:51:29.9086887Z Max attempts: 3; Current attempt: 1; Failed test cases threshold: 30; Failed test cases max limit: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:29.9087136Z [command]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe @C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3668.tmp
2018-04-10T07:51:30.0872809Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.6.0
2018-04-10T07:51:30.0874243Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2018-04-10T07:51:30.0907958Z vstest.console.exe /TestCaseFilter:"FullyQualifiedName=V6TestAutomation.TestTableExplorer.Delete Record|FullyQualifiedName=V6TestAutomation.TestTableExplorer.Create Record"
2018-04-10T07:51:30.0908308Z "D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll"
2018-04-10T07:51:30.0908475Z /logger:"trx"
2018-04-10T07:51:30.0908664Z /TestAdapterPath:"D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\packages"
2018-04-10T07:51:30.3707778Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2018-04-10T07:51:30.6698475Z SpecFlow+Runner execution started
2018-04-10T07:51:30.7564008Z SpecRun: running tests in D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll
2018-04-10T07:51:30.7564629Z Profile: Results
2018-04-10T07:51:30.8100191Z Discovering target: Default
2018-04-10T07:51:30.8100808Z Discovering tests from assembly: D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll
2018-04-10T07:51:33.2194874Z Result: tests executed with warnings
2018-04-10T07:51:33.2195303Z   Total: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:33.2198974Z   Succeeded: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:33.2204195Z   Ignored: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:33.2204453Z   Pending: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:33.2204660Z   Skipped: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:33.2204862Z   Failed: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:33.2205031Z   Execution Time: 00:00:00.1429995
2018-04-10T07:51:33.2205259Z Report file: file:///D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075130.html
2018-04-10T07:51:33.2241215Z Log file: file:///D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075130.log
2018-04-10T07:51:33.2264814Z SpecFlow+Runner execution finished
2018-04-10T07:51:33.3474231Z No test is available in D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
2018-04-10T07:51:33.3550733Z Attachments:
2018-04-10T07:51:33.3551210Z   C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\ktqh3alc.o31\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075130.log
2018-04-10T07:51:33.3551627Z   C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\ktqh3alc.o31\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075130.html
2018-04-10T07:51:33.3737235Z **************** Completed test execution *********************
2018-04-10T07:51:33.3742156Z Test results files: D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\VssAdministrator_factoryvm-az261_2018-04-10_07_51_13.trx
2018-04-10T07:51:33.3778622Z Updating test results: 39
2018-04-10T07:51:33.3806561Z Publishing test results to test run '450'.
2018-04-10T07:51:33.5064845Z Test results remaining: 39. Test run id: 450.
2018-04-10T07:51:34.1698821Z Updated test results: 39
2018-04-10T07:51:34.1699499Z Publishing Attachments: 3
2018-04-10T07:51:34.5508376Z Failed tests: 2; Total tests: 39;
2018-04-10T07:51:34.6399978Z **************** Rerunning failed tests for Test run 450 *********************
2018-04-10T07:51:34.6400353Z Max attempts: 3; Current attempt: 2; Failed test cases threshold: 30; Failed test cases max limit: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:34.6400646Z [command]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe @C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp48E7.tmp
2018-04-10T07:51:34.8356823Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.6.0
2018-04-10T07:51:34.8357741Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2018-04-10T07:51:34.8394018Z vstest.console.exe /TestCaseFilter:"FullyQualifiedName=V6TestAutomation.TestTableExplorer.Delete Record|FullyQualifiedName=V6TestAutomation.TestTableExplorer.Create Record"
2018-04-10T07:51:34.8394448Z "D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll"
2018-04-10T07:51:34.8394775Z /logger:"trx"
2018-04-10T07:51:34.8395040Z /TestAdapterPath:"D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\packages"
2018-04-10T07:51:35.1104820Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2018-04-10T07:51:35.3962945Z SpecFlow+Runner execution started
2018-04-10T07:51:35.4856434Z SpecRun: running tests in D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll
2018-04-10T07:51:35.4857610Z Profile: Results
2018-04-10T07:51:35.5388466Z Discovering target: Default
2018-04-10T07:51:36.2348959Z Discovering tests from assembly: D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll
2018-04-10T07:51:37.8740951Z Result: tests executed with warnings
2018-04-10T07:51:37.8741119Z   Total: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:37.8741196Z   Succeeded: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:37.8741271Z   Ignored: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:37.8741367Z   Pending: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:37.8741441Z   Skipped: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:37.8741515Z   Failed: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:37.8741594Z   Execution Time: 00:00:00.1390451
2018-04-10T07:51:37.8741720Z Report file: file:///D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075135.html
2018-04-10T07:51:37.8795841Z Log file: file:///D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075135.log
2018-04-10T07:51:37.8799980Z SpecFlow+Runner execution finished
2018-04-10T07:51:37.9989204Z No test is available in D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
2018-04-10T07:51:38.0066895Z Attachments:
2018-04-10T07:51:38.0070117Z   C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\qj2sdzi0.2zo\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075135.log
2018-04-10T07:51:38.0070466Z   C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\qj2sdzi0.2zo\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075135.html
2018-04-10T07:51:38.0255222Z **************** Completed test execution *********************
2018-04-10T07:51:38.0260460Z Test results files: D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\VssAdministrator_factoryvm-az261_2018-04-10_07_51_13.trx
2018-04-10T07:51:38.0286385Z Updating test results: 39
2018-04-10T07:51:38.0286821Z Publishing test results to test run '450'.
2018-04-10T07:51:38.1088816Z Test results remaining: 39. Test run id: 450.
2018-04-10T07:51:38.8928593Z Updated test results: 39
2018-04-10T07:51:38.8929427Z Publishing Attachments: 3
2018-04-10T07:51:39.3643307Z Failed tests: 2; Total tests: 39;
2018-04-10T07:51:39.4770115Z **************** Rerunning failed tests for Test run 450 *********************
2018-04-10T07:51:39.4770400Z Max attempts: 3; Current attempt: 3; Failed test cases threshold: 30; Failed test cases max limit: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:39.4771471Z [command]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe @C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5BC4.tmp
2018-04-10T07:51:39.6540115Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.6.0
2018-04-10T07:51:39.6540767Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2018-04-10T07:51:39.6575246Z vstest.console.exe /TestCaseFilter:"FullyQualifiedName=V6TestAutomation.TestTableExplorer.Delete Record|FullyQualifiedName=V6TestAutomation.TestTableExplorer.Create Record"
2018-04-10T07:51:39.6575652Z "D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll"
2018-04-10T07:51:39.6576107Z /logger:"trx"
2018-04-10T07:51:39.6576343Z /TestAdapterPath:"D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\packages"
2018-04-10T07:51:39.9186431Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2018-04-10T07:51:40.2173519Z SpecFlow+Runner execution started
2018-04-10T07:51:40.3177982Z SpecRun: running tests in D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll
2018-04-10T07:51:40.3178533Z Profile: Results
2018-04-10T07:51:40.3718045Z Discovering target: Default
2018-04-10T07:51:40.3728894Z Discovering tests from assembly: D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll
2018-04-10T07:51:42.7354487Z Result: tests executed with warnings
2018-04-10T07:51:42.7358260Z   Total: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:42.7361861Z   Succeeded: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:42.7366617Z   Ignored: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:42.7366911Z   Pending: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:42.7367075Z   Skipped: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:42.7367232Z   Failed: 0
2018-04-10T07:51:42.7367423Z   Execution Time: 00:00:00.1520062
2018-04-10T07:51:42.7367608Z Report file: file:///D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075140.html
2018-04-10T07:51:42.7400258Z Log file: file:///D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075140.log
2018-04-10T07:51:42.7400615Z SpecFlow+Runner execution finished
2018-04-10T07:51:42.8538664Z No test is available in D:\a\r1\a\Test Automation\bin\V6TestAutomation.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
2018-04-10T07:51:42.8612084Z Attachments:
2018-04-10T07:51:42.8612798Z   C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\yetfa5qk.yec\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075140.log
2018-04-10T07:51:42.8613054Z   C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\yetfa5qk.yec\V6TestAutomation_Results_2018-04-10T075140.html
2018-04-10T07:51:42.8800667Z **************** Completed test execution *********************
2018-04-10T07:51:42.8806717Z Test results files: D:\a\r1\a\TestResults\VssAdministrator_factoryvm-az261_2018-04-10_07_51_13.trx
2018-04-10T07:51:42.8852645Z Updating test results: 39
2018-04-10T07:51:42.8852918Z Publishing test results to test run '450'.
2018-04-10T07:51:42.9670889Z Test results remaining: 39. Test run id: 450.
2018-04-10T07:51:44.0187591Z Updated test results: 39
2018-04-10T07:51:44.0187889Z Publishing Attachments: 3
2018-04-10T07:51:44.2739520Z ##[warning]Maximum number of attempts running the failed tests reached: 3
2018-04-10T07:51:44.3511297Z Completed TestExecution Model...
2018-04-10T07:51:44.4323867Z ##[section]Finishing: Execute Automated Tests
```

Comment: Could you share your release log? I've tested on my side, if a test case in the test suite fail in Visual Studio Test task, then this task and the whole release would fail too.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I've updated the question to contain key parts of the release logs (had to shorten due to character constraints).Thanks.

Comment: It seems you've selected "Rerun failed tests", and there is no error when rerun failed tests.

Comment: Can you share all of your settings for the test task?

Comment: While it won't solve your tests not executing, you can use my Ensure Tests task to ensure that the release fails if tests fail to run: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.vsts-ensure-tests-tasks